# python continue download from where I left off

Tags: python, download

I'm trying to download a very large file in collab to my gDrive.  Sometimes the connection cuts out, and It requires I restart.  Is there a way I can download from where I left off?

My code looks like so:

```
from requests import get
import sys

def download(url, file_name):
    # open in binary mode
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        print("Downloading %s" % file_name)
        response = get(url, stream=True)
        total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')

        if total_length is None: # no content length header
            f.write(response.content)
        else:
            dl = 0
            total_length = int(total_length)
            for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                dl += len(data)
                f.write(data)
                done = int(50 * dl / total_length)
                sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s]" % ('=' * done, ' ' * (50-done)) )    
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Why don't use `curl` command to download large file you can also `resume` download operation later

Comment: @devp Thanks this worked perfect and has all the functionality I need